# Basing on~ the differences of these similar meaning words

Tags: grammar

> 試験の成績_____、合格か不合格かを決める。
>
> A. に伴って B. に基づいて C. 次第で D. のもとで E. に応じて

Which of the following fits the blank space best? They all have similar meanings from how I see it (but definitely different usages) : to base on something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. xxに伴ってyy means at the same time as an event/action like xx, yy occurs as well. The results of a test aren't an event/action. Knowing the said results could be such an event.

B. xxに基づいてyy means to use xx as the standard/basis to do yy. The results of the test are <strike>probably not the only thing</strike> used to judge whether or not someone passes <strike>(homework and other tests probably matter too)</strike>.

C. xx次第でyy means depending on xx, yy might or might not happen. The important thing though is that the subject/topic changes depending on the condition xx. The subject/topic is clearly the person taking the class, which certainly does not change. If instead it was 合格か不合格かは試験の成績次第だ, that would be acceptable. See more here: https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/how-to-express-conditions/#1.

EDIT: Or even better suggestion from the comments: 試験の成績次第で、合格か不合格かが決まる。

D. のもとで means under the control/influence of someone or something. Specifically, the **under** part is quite important. The results of a test aren't really a thing that imposes a system that controls whether or not one passes.

E. xxに応じて means the object changes depending on the condition xx. In this case, the object is 合格か不合格か as it is marked with を, and it clearly changes depending on the results of the test.

<strike>The answer should be E.</strike>

EDIT: Looks like the answer is B. I believe E is invalid because there's no active subjective actor that decides whether or not you pass. B is entirely objectively based on a standard (a rubric).

Comment: `The answer should be E` -- Naw.. It should be B 「～に基づいて」.. (You're right about C, though. 試験の成績**次第で**合格か不合格か**が決まる**)

Comment: @Chocolate Whoops! You should probably just write up an answer of your own with the correct answer. I'm guessing the reason I'm wrong is that there's no subjective actor that makes the decision on whether or not one passes...